# Current, Potential difference and fixed resistor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance

[image: Question Picture]

So from my understanding V = IR, so I = V/R.

Shouldn't the calculation for this problem be 9V / 20 Ohms?

However, I do not see an answer for 0.45A.

The answer is 0.3A.

Am I reading the question wrong?

Comment: The 9V battery applies to BOTH the $20\Omega$ resistor and the lamp, not the resistor alone.

Comment: How can you find the resistance of the lamp? The graph is a curved line. Can you help me?

Comment: The resistor and the lamp is connected in series. So, which quantity is the same for them? Voltage or Current?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The lamp is in series with the resistor, so the current going through the lamp is the same as that going through the resistor. Now, the voltages across the resistor and the lamp must sum to be 9V (the voltage of the source), so using Ohm's law on the resistor we can write this as:

$V_{\mbox{lamp}} = 9 - 20 I$.

For each value of $I$ you can work out the voltage across the lamp. One of these pairs of $(I, V_{\mbox{lamp}})$ should lie on the dashed curve. That will be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Find a point where the voltage of lamp and resistor as to 9 volts and have the same current, the current for which the voltages add to 9 v is what is happening in the circuit.

This is because in series combination current through both will be same and the total voltage of the battery is distributed among battery and lamp.